# How to send and receive CAN message using ISOTP protocol in Python-can which uses CANard library?

Tags: python, can-bus, python-can

I want to send a CAN message which is longer than 8 bytes. I used the CAN-ISOTP protocol in SocketCAN `isotpsend` and `isotprecv` to send and receive the CAN message it worked fine. Likewise how to send and receive CAN message in python-can which uses CANard library? Also, will the message received at the receiver side be fragmented or it will be received as such how it was sent at the sender side because in SocketCAN when I used `isotprecv` the message was received as such how it was sent at the sender side and was not fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [can-isotp](http://can-isotp.readthedocs.io), the `isotp.TransportLayer` object implements ISO-TP in Python and is non-hardware dependent.

You'll have to provide 2 callbacks to interface with Canard (sending and receiving). The rest is handled by the TranportLayer object.